# Where can I find a Complete Spoiler list of Risk Legacy's packets & pockets?

Tags: components, risk-legacy

In short, I need a list of all the cards contained in all the packets and pockets.

Background: I completely played through a copy of Risk Legacy with some friends at the beginning of this year, it was great, we all enjoyed ourselves and noted we would like to do it again. However, one of the friends involved in Risk Legacy play through has moved to the otherside of the country and I am setting up to run a campaign of it on Roll20, but I realized our lack of meticulous documenting on our physical playthrough has now caught up to us (we tore up all the cards we were told to destroy after using them) as I am missing a bunch of cards and faction stickers to recreate the vanilla game. Does anyone know where i could find such a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A complete list of what is in each packet can be found in this [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6q--CzixaSKeExoMnJLV2Q5bUE/view?usp=drivesdk&resourcekey=0-gADIIYfnMRrLQxfG0ogk8Q) I have made publicly available.**

I wasn't able to find any one distinct source, however by reconstructing the starting powers with the help of this question [Which Faction Power will result in the greatest bonus troops and/or fewest troop losses?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/which-faction-power-will-result-in-the-greatest-bonus-troops-and-or-fewest-troop) and reading a series of blogposts giving a breakdown of a campaign on [BoardgameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/blogger/1567/stephen-rochelle) I was able to come up with a comprehensive list to help me and my friends play a new campaign with our existing map.

Comment: I'd like to know if anyone have access to Joshua's Word doc he mentioned. I try to access it but it appears to be offline.

Comment: @marcospanontin I have upfated this with a new, non broken link

Comment: Does the general distaste for link only answers apply here?